# How to use CSGTree for multiple boolean operations

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, cgal, csg, libigl

I'm trying to make use of [Csg Tree](https://libigl.github.io/tutorial/#csg-tree) by libigl to do multiple boolean operations at once. In the linked tutorial, there is just this one line:

```cpp
// Compute result of (A ∩ B) \ ((C ∪ D) ∪ E)
igl::copyleft::cgal::CSGTree<MatrixXi> CSGTree =
  {{{VA,FA},{VB,FB},"i"},{{{VC,FC},{VD,FD},"u"},{VE,FE},"u"},"m"};
```

I couldn't figure out how to use the [`CSGTree` class API](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/682e4b9685d2737215f6629ecafcb318d714d556/include/igl/copyleft/cgal/CSGTree.h#L27). Can anybody help ideally by a boilerplate example?

Comment: There is [this example](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/issues/560) but it is *not* quite clear yet ...

Comment: Also, there is [this unit test](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/master/tests/include/igl/copyleft/cgal/CSGTree.cpp) which is just doing one operation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the libigl tutorial:

> Libigl uses exact arithmetic internally to construct the intermediary boolean results robustly. “Rounding” this result to floating point (even double precision) would cause problems if re-injected into a further boolean operation. To facilitate CSG tree operations and encourage callers not to call igl::copyleft::cgal::mesh_boolean multiple times explicitly, libigl implements a class igl::copyleft::cgal::CSGTree.

In simple words - you can construct [CSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) meshes using the `mesh_boolean` function, but in this case you have to explicitly take care of robustness of intermediate calculations. The `CSGTree` class does that for you automatically because it uses the [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) exact arithmetic for all the intermediate calculations with coordinates. Another benefit of the `CSGTree` class - you can construct a multilevel CSG tree in just one line of code. An example below shows how to construct a simplest CSG tree from two meshes and visualize it:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <igl/copyleft/cgal/CSGTree.h>
#include <igl/opengl/glfw/Viewer.h>
#include <igl/read_triangle_mesh.h>

int main()
{
  // ------ load mesh #1
  Eigen::MatrixXd V1;
  Eigen::MatrixXi F1;
  igl::read_triangle_mesh("data/sphere.obj", V1, F1);
  // ------ load mesh #2
  Eigen::MatrixXd V2;
  Eigen::MatrixXi F2;
  igl::read_triangle_mesh("data/xcylinder.obj", V2, F2);
  // ------ combine meshes #1 and #2
  const igl::copyleft::cgal::CSGTree t{{V1, F1}, {V2, F2}, "union"};
  // ------ plot the combined mesh
  const auto V = t.cast_V<Eigen::MatrixXd>();
  const auto F = t.F();
  igl::opengl::glfw::Viewer viewer;
  viewer.data().set_mesh(V, F);
  viewer.launch();
}
```

Such a one-line construction is possible because the `CSGTree` has the following constructor (among others):

```
CSGTree(const CSGTree & A, const CSGTree & B, const MeshBooleanType & type)
```

As you can see above - the resulting array of coordinates can be converted to an array of doubles by the `cast_V` templated function if it's necessary - for example, for visualization. The result of this visualization is below:

[image: SphereUnionXCylinder]